# Magento 2 Hide top navigation links on Desktop View

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

I need to hide magento 2 store top navigation menu from the desktop view but visible on mobile view. How can this be done ?

Comment: can you add picture of top navigation links.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @ShoaibMunir i have solved this issue.

Comment: If your solution is different than my answer, I would suggest you add it in answer so that it would helpful for others in future

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways to do this.

**One with CSS**

Add media query and hide from desktop while `display:block` in mobile

```
.Your_Class{
    display:none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .Your_Class{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

**The other way is by php mobile device check.**

Add a helper function in any of your module

in any helper add `isMobile` function `app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function isMobile(){
        //return true;
        $regex_match = "/(nokia|iphone|ipad|motorola|^mot\-|softbank|foma|docomo|kddi|up\.browser|up\.link|"
            . "htc|dopod|blazer|netfront|helio|hosin|huawei|novarra|CoolPad|webos|techfaith|palmsource|"
            . "blackberry|alcatel|amoi|ktouch|nexian|samsung|^sam\-|s[cg]h|^lge|ericsson|philips|sagem|wellcom|bunjalloo|maui|"
            . "symbian|smartphone|mmp|midp|wap|phone|windows ce|iemobile|^spice|^bird|^zte\-|longcos|pantech|gionee|^sie\-|portalmmm|"
            . "jig\s browser|hiptop|^ucweb|^benq|haier|^lct|opera\s*mobi|opera\*mini|320x320|240x320|176x220"
            . ")/i";

        //DISPLAY DESKTOP THEME ON HAUWEI TAB
        if(preg_match("/(huaweimediapad)/i", strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))){
            return false;
        }

        if (preg_match($regex_match, strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
            return TRUE;
        }

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) && ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE']))))) {
            return TRUE;
        }

        if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android") && stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"mobile")){

            return true;

        }

        if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android")){

            return false;

        }



        $mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
        $mobile_agents = array(
            'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
            'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
            'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
            'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
            'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
            'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
            'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
            'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
            'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

        if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
            return TRUE;
        }

        if (isset($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']) && strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini') > 0) {
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

This function will check if customer is visiting from mobile or desktop

Now use this function in your phtml like this:

```
<?php $isMobile = $this->helper('\Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->isMobile(); ?>
<?php if($isMobile){ ?>
    <?php //Call mobile menu here ?>
<?php } ?>
```